# R ggplot stat_summary: How to add a kde graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density

Id like to use the ggplot stat_summary function with something like geom = "histogram" or geom = "kde". This is avail in python with kind="kde", but I am unable to find a good workaround in r. Thank you.

```
library(ggplot2)
data("iris")
ggplot(iris, aes(iris$Species, iris$Sepal.Length))+
stat_summary(fun.y= " mean", geom = "bar")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`ggalt` package](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggalt)

```r
library(ggalt)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

m <- ggplot(faithful, aes(x = eruptions, y = waiting)) +
       geom_point() +
       xlim(0.5, 6) +
       ylim(40, 110)

m + geom_bkde2d(bandwidth=c(0.5, 4))
```

[image]

```r
m + stat_bkde2d(bandwidth=c(0.5, 4), aes(fill = ..level..), geom = "polygon")
```

[image]

Or use the default from `ggplot2` package

```r
m + geom_density_2d()
```

[image]

```r
m + stat_density_2d(aes(fill = calc(level)), geom = "polygon")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you- I was looking for a way to do it with stat_summary for the mean